# How to sleep with in time range in java

Tags: java

I have a program in java which should run from 9:30 PM to next day 10:00 AM. During this time the program should run every hour; for that I have used `Thread.sleep(60*60*1000)`.

This runs every hour - how can I modify this so that it only executes during this time interval, and sleeps while it's outside the interval?

Comment: You need to use schedulers, search Java Schedules in search engine to get more information.

Comment: Maybe you can use [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)

Comment: If you are using Linux os you can use cron. But it is very unclear what you want. The solution maybe very different, if you run a program on Shell or in a application Server or whatever

Answer (score 1):

Just do your sleeping as you currently are, then when the timer triggers, check the current time using [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html) or equivalent. If the time isn't between the time range you want, don't do anything (or exit, etc). If you are in the time range, perform your actions.

Alternatively, use a [`ScheduledExecutionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), which may offer better accuracy/reliability over long time ranges than a normal `Timer`.

If your needs are more "enterprise", then as the comments say, it might be better to use a framework dedicated for this rather than rolling your own code.

Comment: It's always better to use frameworks (like Quartz) designed for such purpose than re-inventing wheel.

Comment: @PradeepSimha I'd say it depends on the task - this doesn't seem to be a complicated task, and it may be simpler/faster to just write the few extra lines of code required to do this, rather than add in a whole external library.
Besides, this doesn't seem like a particularly large wheel to reinvent! Edit: I've updated my answer to present both views though, as I agree with you as long as the context is right.

Comment: could u please let me know, how I can do this...i can not use cron tab bcz of my company restriction.

Comment: The links in the question provide examples. Given that eg. `LocalTime` implements `Comparable`, you should be able to extrapolate.